# Add colspan and rowspan on table on the fly

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to add colspan or rowspan on a table data

The situation is like I have a table of say 5x5, I want to merge columns by selecting say 2 columns by selecting them with mouse and want to merge. This is easy and I'm able to do till this but issue comes when

[image: table with colspan]

yellow shows colspan(merged)

and I try to do something like

[image: Red shows what I want to merge]

Red shows what I want to merge so the final output should be all six cells merged into 1 and there are many other case of this type which can be seen.
So please guide me the way to proceed for the same.

Comment: Do your cells contain any data? I guess you need jQuery function that would do that automatically? When you merge cells, do you always merge with cells to the right and below as in example or should it be optional?

Comment: The question is unclear, if you were able to merge columns and rows what problem are you running into when merging the 6 cells.

Comment: @Daniel - i gave a simplest scenario where this issue may come and have seen some other issues as well which are even more complex then the one explained. 
Bizniztime - it needs to be free flow a person can start from right most cell and select till first one or can merge 2 cells each from 2 rows in 1 go basically a block of 4(2x2) should be merged

Comment: @Varun: so you want the minimal rectangle that encloses all the selected cells and does not split any rows/cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, perhaps not the most elegant but it works, i hope it works for you:

first prepare the table with attributes.

```
function prepare()
    {
        var row = 0;
        $('table tr').each(function ()
        {
            var tr = $(this);
            var curCol = 0;
            var caught = $(this).data('caught');
            $('td', this).each(function (index)
            {
                while (caught && caught[curCol])
                    curCol++;

                var colspan = $(this).attr('colspan') || 1;
                var rowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');

                $(this).attr('start', curCol);
                $(this).attr('end', curCol + colspan - 1);
                $(this).attr('startrow', row);
                $(this).attr('endrow', row + rowspan - 1);



                var next_tr = tr.next();
                for (var i = 0; i < rowspan - 1; i++)
                {
                    var curCaught = next_tr.data('caught') || [];
                    for (var j = curCol; j < curCol + colspan; j++)
                        curCaught[j] = true;
                    next_tr.data('caught', curCaught);
                    next_tr = next_tr.next();
                }

                curCol += colspan;
            });
            row++;
        })
    }
```

then you can call this function sending it the selected tdies:

```
function getBoundingRectangle(tds)
    {
        var minCol = tds.min(function(){return $(this).attr('start');});
        var maxCol = tds.max(function(){return $(this).attr('end');});

        var minrow = tds.min(function(){return $(this).attr('startrow');});
        var maxrow = tds.max(function(){return $(this).attr('endrow');});

        var rec = $('td').filter(function()
        {
            var startRow = $(this).attr('startrow');
            var startCol = $(this).attr('start');

            var endRow = $(this).attr('endrow');
            var endCol = $(this).attr('end');

        return (startRow >= minrow && startRow <= maxrow && startCol >= minCol && startCol <= maxCol) ||
               (endRow >= minrow && endRow <= maxrow && endCol >= minCol && endCol <= maxCol);
        });

        if (rec.length == tds.length)
        {
            debugger;
            var first = rec.filter('[start=' + minCol + '][startrow=' + minrow + ']')
            rec.not(first).remove();
            first.attr('colspan', maxCol - minCol + 1);
            first.attr('rowspan', maxrow - minrow + 1);

            return rec;
        }
        else return getBoundingRectangle(rec);
    }
```

also add the next utility functions:

```
$.fn.max = function(func)
    {
        var arr = this.map(func).toArray();

        return Math.max.apply( Math, arr );

    };

    $.fn.min = function(func)
    {
        var arr = this.map(func).toArray();

        return Math.min.apply( Math, arr );

    };
```

Comment: much appreciated efforts will test it tomorrow. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: What is tds in `getBoundingRectangle` is it an array or wat?

Comment: it's a jQuery object containing all the selected tds (those the user chose to merge) so omethng on the lines of: getBoundingRectangle($('.selected'))

Comment: you had it written before hand or wrote it for the answer?

Comment: i wrote it for the answer :). i treat it like a riddle and if i can help at the same time that's great. I hope this assisted you.

Answer (score 1):

Today i wrote function to automatically cell rowspan for selected columns

```
function rowspan(tableClass, rowClass) {

 var cellThis, cellPrev, spanning;

 $("." + tableClass + " ." + rowClass).each(function () {
      cellThis = $(this);
      spanning = 0;

      if (cellPrev) {
           if ($(cellPrev).html() == $(cellThis).html()) {
                $(cellThis).remove();
                $(cellPrev).prop("rowspan", parseInt($(cellPrev).prop("rowspan")) + 1);
                spanning = 1;
           }
      }


      if (spanning == 0) {
           cellPrev = $(this);
      }
 });

}
```

There is an example of my function: http://jsfiddle.net/6L25e/