# Insert multiple rows in a cell in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to insert rows within a cell in HTML Table using jquery, I want something like this:

```
--------------
ID | Sec | Div
--------------
1  | S1  | D1
   | S2  | D2
   | S3  | D3
--------------
2  | S3  | D3
   | S4  | D4
   | S5  | D5
--------------
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
function insertRows(this){


var Rows1 = '<tr><td> S1 </td></tr><tr><td> S2 </td></tr><tr><td> S3 </td></tr>'
var Rows2 = '<tr><td> S3 </td></tr><tr><td> S4 </td></tr><tr><td> S5 </td></tr>'

this.srcElement.parentElement.nextSibling.outerHTML = Rows1
this.srcElement.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.outerHTML = Rows2

}
```

What is does is, it inserts all in the same Row, something like this:

```
---------------------
ID | Sec     | Div
---------------------
1  | S1S2S3  | D1D2D3
---------------------
2  | S3S4S5  | D3D4D5
---------------------
```

How can I make this to work?

Comment: There is no concept of having "rows within cells"... you either need to implement the `rowspan` attribute, or implement a table structure **within** each cell, for example

Comment: Make sure you insert complete tables within the cell that start and end with proper table tags.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery... then use jQuery.

Comment: There is no jQuery code visible. And `this` is a keyword, don't use it as a parameter.

Answer (score 11):

You Can Fullfill your requirement without using jquery
just Paste this Code inside body tag

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td >ID</td>
 <td>SEC</td>
 <td>DIV</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="3">1</td>
 <td>S1</td>
 <td>D1</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td>S2</td>
<td>D2</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>S3</td>
<td>D3</td>

</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">---------------------</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>SEC</td>
<td>DIV</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">2</td>
<td>S1</td>
<td>D1</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>S2</td>
<td>D2</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>S3</td>
<td>D3</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

here you can find live example http://jsfiddle.net/Anujyadav123/AdQy3/

Answer (score 0):

take a look here [Add colspan and rowspan on table on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109247/add-colspan-and-rowspan-on-table-on-the-fly)

***OR***

is it important to add row, if not you are able to add your values into cell

***Example:***

```
function showP(){
     txt1 = $($('#myTable').find('TR').find('TD')[1]).html()+'</br>S1'
     txt3 = $($('#myTable').find('TR').find('TD')[3]).html()+'</br>D1'

     $($('#myTable').find('TR').find('TD')[1]).html(txt1 )
     $($('#myTable').find('TR').find('TD')[3]).html(txt3 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` is rather broken when dealing with tables, at least under IE.

Your choices are:

1. Restrict the use of `.innerHTML` to only change the contents of a `td` element.
2. Use `.innerHTML` to replace the ENTIRE table structure
3. Use `DOM` methods to manipulate table rows and table cells.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces